# Weird datetime format in iCloud calendar

Tags: icloud, icalendar, rfc5545

I'm currently working on displaying dates from ical format (fetched via caldav from iCloud). However, the datetime formats aren't consistant, sometimes I get an `VEVENT` like the following:

```
BEGIN:VEVENT
...
DTSTART;TZID=Europe/Berlin:Mond marc 2013 T-001020350 (TIV)
DTEND;TZID=Europe/Berlin:20130315T120000
END:VEVENT
```

The `DTSTART` datetime doesn't make sense to me. Is there any documentation on how to interpret that kind of datetime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not make sense indeed. It does not comply to [RFC5545](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545) so the server should have rejected it.

The only sane thing to do in my opinion is to try to track down the client that generated this and get them to fix their bug. In general, this is indicated by the PRODID property value, although servers sometime rewrite those.

Comment: It's generated by the iCloud calendar itself. Probably have to write to apple then.